# ERROR opening V4L interface: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, webcam, raspberry-pi2, v4l2

I compiled mjpg-streamer in my raspberry pi, but when I run the below command, it occured an eeror shown in the title. Details are below:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/mjpg-streamer-code-182/mjpg-streamer# /usr/local/bin/mjpg_streamer -i "/usr/local/lib/input_uvc.so" -o "/usr/local/lib/output_http.so -w /usr/local/www"
```

Results:

```
MJPG Streamer Version: svn rev: 
i: Using V4L2 device.: /dev/video0
i: Desired Resolution: 640 x 480
i: Frames Per Second.: 5
i: Format............: MJPEG
ERROR opening V4L interface: Operation not permitted
Init v4L2 failed !! exit fatal 
i: init_VideoIn failed
```

How can I get permitted to operate my v4l2?

Comment: Did you try running it with sudo?

Answer (score 3):

If `/dev/video0` is owned by `root video` (check with `ls -l /dev/video0`), add yourself to the video group with `usermod -aG video your_username`, log out, log in, try again. (You'll likely need to be root or prefix with `sudo` to add yourself to the group.)

If you still get 'Operation not permitted', ensure you have set `gpu_mem=128` in `/boot/config.txt`. It was set at 64 by default for me (on Arch Linux ARM), but increasing it to 128 did the trick.

My `/etc/modules-load.d/raspberrypi.conf` looks like this to get the v4l2 module loaded at boot:

```
snd-bcm2835
i2c-dev
bcm2835-v42l2
```

Tested and verified on a Pi 1 B+, and a Pi 3, both running ALARM.